# Enable or disable the selected layer mask

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Can anyone help how I can disable or enable the layer mask of the selected layer?
I wanted to automate it via scrip not with action.

I can't provide any code yet since I don't know yet what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scriptlistener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html) is your friend here.

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF

layermask(true);
alert("Layer mask enabled");
// or
layermask(false);
alert("Layer mask disabled");

// Switch back on any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // ON

function layermask(bool)
{
  // =======================================================
  var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc22 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref5 = new ActionReference();
  var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref5.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
  desc22.putReference( idnull, ref5 );
  var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc23 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idUsrM = charIDToTypeID( "UsrM" );
  desc23.putBoolean( idUsrM, bool ); // value set here
  var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  desc22.putObject( idT, idLyr, desc23 );
  executeAction( idsetd, desc22, DialogModes.NO );

}
```

Using a bit of Action manager code to get the state of the layer mask we can use:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF


var layerMaskState = false;

s2t = stringIDToTypeID;
var r = new ActionReference();
r.putProperty(s2t('property'), s2t('userMaskEnabled'));
r.putEnumerated(s2t('layer'), s2t('ordinal'), s2t('targetEnum'));

// Make sure that the object that executeActionGet
// returns contains this key (which means the layer has a mask):

var d = executeActionGet(r);
if (d.hasKey(s2t('userMaskEnabled')))
{
  layerMaskState = d.getBoolean(s2t('userMaskEnabled'));
}

// Toggle it!
layerMaskState = !layerMaskState;
layer_mask(layerMaskState);


// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // OFF


function layer_mask(bool)
{
  // =======================================================
  var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc22 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref5 = new ActionReference();
  var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref5.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
  desc22.putReference( idnull, ref5 );
  var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var desc23 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idUsrM = charIDToTypeID( "UsrM" );
  desc23.putBoolean( idUsrM, bool ); // set here
  var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
  desc22.putObject( idT, idLyr, desc23 );
  executeAction( idsetd, desc22, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: Wow didn't know about it. Thank you very much